# How to perform POST method in WebAPI in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have created `GET`,`POST`,`PUT` and `DELETE` methods in my sample Web api.

Using fiddler, I am adding resources using `POST` method and getting status 201 created with location.

But when I am calling through its URI, I am getting not found exception.

Comment: Please share what have you tried?

Comment: Share some code with us

Comment: As i am new in RestAPI, i am following this sample : http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations

Comment: What's your client? Web, desktop app or mobile? Be specific because you can consume a web api in different platforms.

Comment: I am learning through microsoft samples : http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations..So my client is Web

Comment: How are you calling the post method? Show us the code for that..

Answer (score 0):

You probably call the POST-method with a GET http method. Then you get a 4xx error.

I suggest using a "Advanced REST client" (search google- chrome plugin) to post your data. Then you can use the right HTTP methods in your web api.

Comment: I think the issue is that he creates the resource with the `POST` request, gets a `201 Created` response with a resource location URI, but this resource location gives him 404.